# Simple CoreData example throwing exception

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

I'm going a little mad I think. This is the *VERY* first thing I do and I get the crash (seen below). The crash is the moment I try to step over the executeFetchRequest.

If I remove request.sortDescriptors= sortDescriptors it works.

I must be doing something insanely stupid. But even after walking away a couple times, I still can't see it. index is a non-optional Integer32, with default of 1.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
   [self defaultData];
}

- (void)defaultData {

   NSManagedObjectContext* moc= self.managedObjectContext; // all code with this 

   [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Envelope" 
      inManagedObjectContext:moc];

   NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest
      fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Envelope"];

   NSArray* sortDescriptors= [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"index"];
   request.sortDescriptors= sortDescriptors;

   NSError* error = nil;
   NSArray* results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
}
```

And here's my crash:

```
-[__NSCFConstantString key]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x240f4
```

Tried deleting the 'iPhone Simulator' folder. Tried deleting and recreating the xcdatamodeld. Perhaps a leak in my nib files (though can't see anything). Tried gcc (currently Apple LLVM 3.1). I've tried moving everything over to a new project. I've tried starting a project completely fresh. I've tried saving the context before doing the fetch.

I already know I'm going to hate the answer. It's going to be stupid, I'm going to feel foolish, but I need another set of eyes.

Thanks
Greg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sortDescriptors` is supposed to be an array of `NSSortDescriptor`; your `sortDescriptors` just has `@"index"` (an `NSString`). Try this:

```
NSArray* sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"index" ascending:NO]];
request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;
```

Comment: Thank you :( I knew I was going to hate that answer.